# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0.33913043 0.36086956 0.4173913 ... 0.52608699 0.56956524 0.53913045]

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

i am working on a smile recognition using **openCV**, i wrote the code and reached the command line below:

```
def test_recognition(c1, c2):
    subplot(121)
    extracted_face1 = extract_face_features(gray1, face1[0], (c1, c2))
    imshow(extracted_face1, cmap='gray')
    print(predict_face_is_smiling(extracted_face1))
    subplot(122)
    extracted_face2 = extract_face_features(gray2, face2[0], (c1, c2))
    imshow(extracted_face2, cmap='gray')
    print(predict_face_is_smiling(extracted_face2))
```

then when i ran the code below:

```
interact(test_recognition,
         c1=(0.0, 0.3, 0.01),
         c2=(0.0, 0.3, 0.01))
```

it gave me this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\interaction.py
>   in update(self, *args)
>       249                     value = widget.get_interact_value()
>       250                     self.kwargs[widget._kwarg] = value
>   --> 251                 self.result = self.f(**self.kwargs)
>       252                 show_inline_matplotlib_plots()
>       253                 if self.auto_display and self.result is not None:
>
> in test_recognition(c1, c2)
>         3     extracted_face1 = extract_face_features(gray1, face1[0], (c1, c2))
>         4     imshow(extracted_face1, cmap='gray')
>   ----> 5     print(predict_face_is_smiling(extracted_face1))
>         6     subplot(122)
>         7     extracted_face2 = extract_face_features(gray2, face2[0], (c1, c2))
>
> in
>   predict_face_is_smiling(extracted_face)
>         1 def predict_face_is_smiling(extracted_face):
>   ----> 2     return svc_1.predict(extracted_face.ravel())
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in predict(self, X)
>       574             Class labels for samples in X.
>       575         """
>   --> 576         y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
>       577         return self.classes_.take(np.asarray(y, dtype=np.intp))
>       578
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in predict(self, X)
>       323         y_pred : array, shape (n_samples,)
>       324         """
>   --> 325         X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
>       326         predict = self._sparse_predict if self._sparse else self._dense_predict
>       327         return predict(X)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in
>   _validate_for_predict(self, X)
>       456 
>       457         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, order="C",
>   --> 458                         accept_large_sparse=False)
>       459         if self._sparse and not sp.isspmatrix(X):
>       460             X = sp.csr_matrix(X)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
>   check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order,
>   copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
>   ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       550                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
>       551                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
>   --> 552                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
>       553 
>       554         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes
>
> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0.33913043
>   0.36086956 0.4173913  ... 0.52608699 0.56956524 0.53913045]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
>   feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

**Any hint about how to fix this?**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

The TraceBack of the code literally contains the answer to your question.

`Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

You have to create a Numpy NDArray instead of an Array and reshape it them to be accepted by the code.

Comment: i know i have to do this, but where?, in which line i must add this?